# Does TradingView pine scipt have ta.bbands function? It's not working for me

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

So i want to build a pine v5 strategy with bolliger bands indicator but i keep getting this error: Could not find function or function reference 'bbands' in line 28

```
//@version=5
strategy("Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
//@version=5

indicator(shorttitle="BB", title="Bollinger Bands", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
mult = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev")
basis = ta.sma(src, length)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
offset = input.int(0, "Offset", minval = -500, maxval = 500)

// Импорт индикаторов
stochRSI = ta.stoch(close, high, low, length=14)[0]
[MACD, signal, hist] = ta.macd(close, fastlen=12, slowlen=26, siglen=9)
MACD := MACD, signal := signal, hist := hist
EMA = ta.ema(close, length=20)
[bb_upper, bb_mid, bb_lower] = bbands(close, length=20, mult=2.0)

bb_upper := bb_upper, bb_mid := bb_mid, bb_lower := bb_lower

// Задание цели прибыли в 100 тиков от цены входа
profit_target = 100

if (stochRSI > 80 and MACD > 0 and EMA > ta.ema(close,length=9) and bb_upper > bb_mid)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long) // Вход в длинную позицию
    strategy.exit("Long TP", "Long", profit = profit_target) // Выход по цели прибыли

if (stochRSI < 20 and MACD < 0 and EMA < ta.ema(close,length=9) and bb_lower < bb_mid)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short) // Вход в короткую позицию
    strategy.exit("Short TP", "Short", profit = profit_target) // Выход по цели прибыли

if (stochRSI < 20 and MACD < 0 and EMA > ta.ema(close,length=9) and bb_upper < bb_mid)
    strategy.close("Long") // Закрытие длинной позиции без достижения цели прибыли

if (stochRSI > 80 and MACD > 0 and EMA < ta.ema(close,length=9) and bb_lower > bb_mid)
    strategy.close("Short") // Закрытие короткой позиции без достижения цели прибыли

// Отрисовка индикатора Боллинджер бандс
plot(basis,"Basis",color=#FF6D00 ,offset = offset)
p1 = plot(upper,"Upper",color=#2962FF ,offset = offset)
p2 = plot(lower,"Lower",color=#2962FF ,offset = offset)
fill(p1,p2,title="Background",color=color.rgb(33 ,150 ,243 ,95))
```

I tried to to replace this string
`[bb_upper, bb_mid, bb_lower] = ta.bbands(close, length=20, mult=2.0)`
with this:
`[bb_upper, bb_mid, bb_lower] = ta.bbands(close, 20, 2.0)`
and with this:
`[bb_upper, bb_mid, bb_lower] = bbands(close, 20, 2.0)`

but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

try it with ta.bb instead of ta.bbands, hope it will fix